# import XML to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have a string of XML that represents some HTML tags. I want to select some of the XML and import it to HTML.

An example of what i'm currently doing:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div><p>som text</p></div>
<h1>hi there</h1>
<button>click</button>
<script>

   xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><html><a href="#">the new link</a></html></root>';
   $xml =$($.parseXML( xml ));

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var content = $xml.find('html:first').contents();
    content.appendTo('body');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code should append a link at the end of the page but I can only see text, its not link. No HTML tag works.

I used another library to do this instead of jQuery like https://github.com/jindw/xmldom , but the result is same.
update : this is the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/V4gHz/

Comment: .html() doesnt work with xml document. because it use innerHTML function inside.

Comment: What about `.text()` ?

Comment: nope. not working at all

Comment: What you append here is an `Element` object (as you can see using a browser’s Developer Tools), not an `HTMLElement` object, so it won’t be interpreted as an HTML element.

Comment: you should provide jsfiddle so we could test ourselves and fix your problem

Comment: yes, i loged the object and it was not HTMLElement, but when i look the source in the developrt tools , every thing is ok , i have '<a href="#">the new link</a>' at the end of the page but browser treat with it like garbage text. why? even if thats the problem what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find answer to my own question. the thing is dont wast your time with innerHTML or XMLSerializer . becuase they dont work for all browsers and they are just compatible with firefox. and jquery solutions like $.contents() or $.HTML() also work only for firefox and doesnt work for opera , chrome and IE.

i find a jquery plugin called 'htmlize' wiche is real serializer. the plugin address is : https://github.com/ZeeAgency/jquery.htmlize

you can find additional information from github. and this is how my problem solved :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div><p>som text</p></div>
  <h1>hi there</h1>
  <button>click</button>
  <script>

    xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><html><a href="#">the new link</a></html></root>';
    $xml =$($.parseXML( xml ));

 $('button').on('click',function(){
    var content = $xml.find('html:first').htmlize();
     $(content).appendTo('body');
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```