# HTML Tag For Import XML

Tags: html, xml

I really don't know what is best question words for this

when you try to import css and js , you will use :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i builed a xml generator for build xml format for each pages. 
but now what is the tag for use xml ? (for seo absolutely)
thanks and sorry for my poor englush.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070979/import-xml-to-html) SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one, and it doesn't make sense to have one.

CSS is a stylesheet language designed to describe how a DOM should look. Adding to an HTML DOM makes sense.

JavaScript is a programming language, originally designed to run in the context of a webpage and to modify a DOM. Adding it to an HTML DOM makes sense.

XML is a generic means to create a custom markup language. It doesn't make sense to add arbitrary XML to an HTML DOM. Consequently, HTML doesn't provide a means to add it.

You could write JavaScript that retrieves the XML (e.g. using the *fetch* API) and does something with it, but that involves custom programming where the programmer, not the browser, determines what is done with the XML.

Comment: so it's not matter for seo ?

Comment: Why should search engines care about some custom XML? Is something wrong with your HTML?

Comment: no but i read an article xmls is so good for search engines :(

Comment: Your home made custom XML format is not going to be of a great deal of interest to search engines. Either you misunderstood the article or it is garbage.

Comment: http://localhost/index.php?page=about & http://localhost/xml/?page=about , then the about content show with xml,

Comment: i thinking about that , if i link that like (wp-cms) then maybe good for crawlers